# Debugging android app on target in QtCreator

Tags: android, c++, qt, debugging, qt-creator

When I try to run a Debug build of my application, with the debugger attached, on my phone via USB debugging, I get a message saying:

> This does not seem to be a "Debug" build. Setting breakpoints by file name and line number may fail.

I am able to set breakpoints in my main function, but I cannot get access to intermediate values or set breakpoints in any sub-functions.

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem and the problem in my case was that gdb was being run with the cdb engine.  It may have resulted from corruption in the Qt Creator `profiles.xml` file.

To check, go to <kbd>tools</kbd> -> <kbd>options</kbd> -> <kbd>build</kbd> and <kbd>run</kbd> -> <kbd>kits</kbd> and select the kit you are using. Next, go to the debugger line, choose <kbd>edit</kbd>, and make sure you have the right engine for your debugger.

If that is not it, to debug further, consider looking closely at your Makefiles, execution directories, et c.   Another question that was related to the "does not seem to be a debug build" message was resolved by simply cleaning and rebuilding.   Another solution might be to build a new fresh kit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I'm quite new to Qt and compiling to Android, so I'm still uncertain how to proceed. I have checked the gcc and believe that is correct - The kit I use is Android for arm (GCC 4.8, Qt 5.1.1) and the debugger is set to <NDK-R9 dir>/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-androideabi-gdb. Regarding the Makesfiles - where do I find those? Regarding the "does not seem to be a debug build" I also thought that cleaning and rebuilding would solve that, but I tried to clean and rebuild my project several times without that changing anything :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the following to your .pro file:

```
CONFIG += debug
```